# Custom JLabel that draw a circle

Tags: java

I want a JLabel that draws a circle around it. I have some code already but the circle does not draw, am I doing something wrong here?

```
public class TowerMarker extends JLabel
{
    private int x, y, id;
    private ImageIcon ic;
    private String ql;

    public TowerMarker(int id, int x, int y, ImageIcon ic, String ql)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.ic = ic;
        this.ql = ql;
        setBounds(x, y, 40, 85);
        setIcon(ic);
        setToolTipText("QL: "+ql);
        updateUI();

    }

    @Override
    public int getX()
    {
            return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public String getQL()
    {
        return ql;
    }

    public ImageIcon getImageIcon()
    {
        return ic;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return x+":"+y+":"+ql;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        g.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);

        ui.update(g, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the code using update(...). That is something that might be done When using AWT, but it is not needed in Swing. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `super.paintComponent(g);`

```
 @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        g.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);

        ui.update(g, this);
    }
```

but instead of paintComponent use

```
public void paint( Graphics g )
```

Comment: I tried both, I did not see anything appear around the Label after placed on the JLabel map.

Comment: Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method.